# How to determine the line integral by path?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

$ A(1,0), B(1,1), C(-1,1), D(-1,0) $

$ A(-1,0), B(1,-1), C(-1,-1), D(-1,0) $

$$ \int_C \frac{xdy-ydx}{x^2+y^2} $$

I have this line integral with 8 different points. The first points represent a rectangle if you unite all of the points from A to B and the second points represent a right angle triangle.
The exercise specifies that I have to find the x(t) and y(t) functions for each 8 different points.How do I get that?

Comment: For the first contour, line AD passes through the origin making denominator $(x^2+y^2)$ equal to zero...

Answer (score 0):

For example for the $AB$ path you can take the affine functions

$$\begin{cases}x(t)&=& (1-t)x_A +t x_B&=&1\\y(t)&=&(1-t)y_A  +t y_B&=&t\end{cases} \ \ \ \ \text{for} \ 0 \le t \le 1\tag{1}$$

where $A=(x_A,y_A)$ and $B=(x_B,y_B).$

In this way $A=(x(0),y(0))$ and $B=(x(1),y(1))$.

---

Edit : let us call $\Gamma$ the contour on which you compute the integral. I have said you that this contour must not pass trough the origin. There is a general result (using complex function theory ; have you studied it ?) which is :

$$\int_{\Gamma} \frac{xdy-ydx}{x^2+y^2}=\begin{cases}0&\text{if 0 is exterior to} \ \Gamma\\ \pm2 \pi &\text{if 0 is interior to} \ \Gamma \end{cases},$$

("$+$" sign if $\Gamma$ is counterclockwise (positively) oriented, "$-$" sign otherwise).